# Adding sub contextMenus in Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome

I can currently create a contextMenu (right-click menu) in a Google Chrome extension as follows:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "The name to click",
  contexts:["selection"],
  onclick: theFunctionToRun
});
```

However, I would like to be able to add a contextMenu of submenus. I am implementing 10 tools that can be invoked through the right-click menu, but would like to have 2 menus each with 5 tools in them based on their categorization.

I have not been able to find any info online or in documentation about this. I'm surprised other people do not want this feature as well so maybe I am just searching for the wrong thing.

Is creating a contextMenu of submenus possible? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to specify an id in the parent menu and then reference the parent ID in the other menus as follows:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "The name of the parent menu",
  id: "parent",
  contexts:["selection"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "The first action to click",
  parentId: "parent",
  contexts:["selection"],
  onclick: theFirstFunction
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "The second action to click",
  parentId: "parent",
  contexts:["selection"],
  onclick: theSecondFunction
});
```

Comment: You can also use the return value of `chrome.contextMenus.create()` and use it as a `parentId`, then you don't need to set the `id`.

Comment: @redfoxofdeath It should work. Maybe create another post with your code and someone should respond to it.

Comment: How to create them separately without being collapsed into one single parent item?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC Not exactly sure what you mean, if you remove the parentId line, then they will not be a child entry.

Comment: @kojow7 In [this documentation](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/android/android-4.0/external/chromium/chrome/common/extensions/docs/contextMenus.html) they confirmed this matter. " You can create as many context menu items as you need, but if more than one from your extension is visible at once, Google Chrome automatically collapses them into a single parent menu."

Answer (score 3):

Basically a combination of answers above worked for me. This is my example (there are 2 ways to create menus - declare in var or directly use in `chrome.contextMenus.create`) :

```js
var contextMenuItem = {
    "id": "addRecipe",
    "title": "Add Recipe",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Add new recipe name",
    parentId: "addRecipe",
    id: "name",
    contexts:["selection"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Add shopping list",
    parentId: "addRecipe",
    id: "list",
    contexts:["selection"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Add ingredients",
    parentId: "addRecipe",
    id: "ingredients",
    contexts:["selection"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Add cooking steps",
    parentId: "addRecipe",
    id: "steps",
    contexts:["selection"]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit simpler. First I will own up and say this is not my original code, however, the submenu bit is. 
The code I am basing it on comes from:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH7QVll30XQ and his Github repo
https://github.com/gopinav/Chrome-Extensions. Here' how I changed the event page just added another context menu item.
The parent menu title is the name on the Manifest which I changed just to be sure. I hope this is of some use to somebody.

```
    var priceItem = {
    "id": "saveAsPrice",
    "title": "Save as Price",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

var nameItem = {
    "id": "saveAsName",
    "title": "Save as Name",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};


chrome.contextMenus.create(priceItem);
chrome.contextMenus.create(nameItem);
```

[Chrome Extension Context submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6NPJ.png)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this isn't what I was looking for. I needed to be able to add both parent and child sub menus. You have only included code that is for 'parent' menus without child items.

Answer (score 0):

For **MV3** you can add *sub-menus* to the context menu like this;

```js
const menuId = "myMenu";

function callback1(){
  console.log('my first callback');
};

function callback2(){
  console.log('my second callback');
};

//primary menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id : menuId,
  title : "Menu Name",
  contexts : ["all"]
});

//sub-menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id : "myMenuSub1",
  parentId : menuId,
  title : "An Action",
  contexts : ["all"]
}, callback1);

//sub-menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id : "myMenuSub2",
  parentId : menuId,
  title : "Another Action",
  contexts : ["all"]
}, callback2);
```

#### PREVIEW

[image: context menus chrome extension mv3]

#### ONCLICK EVENTS

To handle onclick events on any of the sub-menus, do something like this:

```js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  console.log(info);
  console.log(tab);
});
```

The **info** parameter returns an object containing the context menu item's data. You can use it to check the sub-menu item that was clicked, and then perform an action on it.

#### INFO PREVIEW

[image]

The **tab** callback parameter returns an object containing the current tab where the sub-menu item was clicked.

#### TAB PREVIEW

[image]